# Open cover with finite subcover implies closed set as set with all limit points contained

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am interested if following line of reasoning can lead to correct proof by contradiction.

Let's assume we have set $X$, each open cover of which have finite subcover. Let's assume here is a limit point $x \notin X$. By definition of limit point, each epsilon-neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap X \ne 0$. That means we can take open cover such that $\forall \epsilon \gt 0: V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap X \in O_e$. But if $x \notin X$, that open cover will not have finite subcover, which cannot be.

I understand this is not close to rigorous proof, but I am interested if it contains the right intuition and can be expanded. My main idea is to try and keep definition of limit point, instead of using definition of closed set being a set containing limits of all Cauchy sequences.

Comment: As you speak of epsilon-neighbourhoods --- can we assume that your space is metric? (Actually, we do not need metric, Hausdorff would be enough)

Comment: The best definition of closed is: the complement is open.
So you may want to try that $X^\complement$ is open, i.e., it is a neighbourhood for each of its point. So, pick $a\in X^\complement$. For every $x\in X$, you can use the Hausdorff property (which I suppose your space has) to find disjoint open sets $U_x$ and $V_x$ such that $a\in U_x$ and $x\in V_x$. Now use the finite subcover property of $X$ to construct an open neighbourhood of $a$ that is disjoint to $X$.